# Imagem no menu WPF com C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou com um problema, criei uma aplicação em WPF, e coloquei um menu que irá ter imagens nos itens. Quando visualizo a imagem no VS está ok, mas quando rodo a aplicação as imagens não aparecem.
No source está assim?

```
<Image Source="Image/minhaimagem.png" />
```

Existe alguma configuração que deva ser feita? ou algo parecido?

Desde já agradeço a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é bem simples:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/**Coloque.Aqui.O.Namespace**;Component/Image/minhaimagem.png" />
```

Comment: Podes exlicar melhor a resposta?

Comment: Sergio neste [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) está bem explicado.

Comment: A ideia do Stack Overflow em Português é ter nas respostas informação sufeciente para o autor da pergunta (AP) perceber melhor o problema e a resposta. Se esse link deixar de funcionar um dia a respost fica pobre. Podes [edit] a resposta e juntar info desse link? diz -me quando fizeres e eu vou dar `+1` :)